# Google Cloud Storage access after end of trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I started a project using the free trial, and now that the trial is over I can't access the data in the bucket.

How can I download the data?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. Contact Google support directly for assistance with your account.

Answer (score 2):

After your trial ends the following will happen (This is just the main points that concerns you for now):

1. All resources are stopped and becomes inaccessible.
2. Any data stored in `Compute Engine` is lost. (You try to access GCS bucket so the data is still there)
3. As soon as trial ends, you have 30 days to retrieve any data created during the trial period (except Compute Engine as stated in 2nd point).

**What to do to recover the data:**

4. Option A) Upgrading to a paid account
5. Option B) "[Contact Google Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) to export any data you stored in GCP services" as stated in the documentation.

All these information can be found in the [GCP Free Tier > Recovering data](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#recovering_data) documentation.